# how to set a childs checked in a radioGroup [java]

Tags: java, swing, radio-group

like i have a radiogroup with 4 Jradiobutton and if i give my function a "3" parameter it checks the third child in the radioGroup, something like Jcombobox.setSelectedIndex(index);

Comment: You might want to investigate `ButtonGroup`

Comment: i didn't get it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> something like Jcombobox.setSelectedIndex(index);

There is no such method.

One solution is to keep an `ArrayList` of all your radio buttons. Then you can access the appropriate button from the list and make it selected.

Or you can use the `ButtonGroup` to get the `Enumeration` of all the buttons. Then you will need to iterate through the Enumeration to find the proper button.